# The reals as an algebra over the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

**R**, the real numbers, is an infinite dimensional commutative division algebra over the rationals **Q**. Is there an example of an infinite dimensional *noncommutative* division algebra over the rationals **Q**?

Comment: Perhaps see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48173/infinite-dimensional-division-algebras-with-finite-center-and-their-involutions

Comment: Can you just take a non-commutative division algebra over the reals (such as the Hamilton quaternions) as your example?

Comment: A more interesting question is to ask for a noncommutative division algebra which is infinite-dimensional, not over its prime subfield, but over its center (which is a field). I don't know any examples off the top of my head but they surely exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure: take any noncommutative division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, like the quaternions. They inherit a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra structure from the embedding $\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and they're clearly infinite dimensional, since $\mathbb{R}$ is already infinite dimensional.

Comment: Why, of course! How silly of me.